# My window form application (c#) built in Visual Studio 2017 got crash after installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, crash, windows-forms-designer, setup-project

I have window form application which i built in visual studio 2017. The installer setup is create with setup installer in visual studio. whenever i install and run the application it got crash. When i look into the windows event viewer i got this

```
Faulting application name: PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe, version: 4.3.5.0, time stamp: 0xc3042173
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4150.0, time stamp: 0x5e176ddd
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x004d4c2a
Faulting process id: 0x2b50
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6159eefbbf7f1
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\POS Accounting\POS- 
Accounting-Setup\PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 5114194f-1bfe-40a0-bb07-46919a936011
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

and in information this:

```
Fault bucket 2100928511447470437, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe
P2: 4.3.5.0
P3: c3042173
P4: clr.dll
P5: 4.8.4150.0
P6: 5e176ddd
P7: c00000fd
P8: 004d4c2a
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER8022.tmp.dmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER85C1.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER85D1.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER85DF.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER85FF.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_PosAccounting-Sa_267e585ade93a8e1ed83cd68c79c7116dddbd66_8523bba8_0a198f07

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 5114194f-1bfe-40a0-bb07-46919a936011
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: b0dbf3a0b3be42bdcd27ff5997511165
Cab Guid: 0
```

Before there were some .net framework error too but i fixed those.
Strange thing is my development build in bin/debug or bin/release run perfectly.
But don't know why with installation its not working.

I ran Fuslogvw.exe also from command prompt to check the assembly failure logs and got this

[image]

I am putting logs for one file below

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (4/18/2020 @ 10:02:24 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\POS Accounting\POS-Accounting-Setup\PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Sage.Collaboration, Version=2020.2.0.219, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d06c16dde04d83e4
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\POS 
Accounting\POS-Accounting-Setup\PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/Sage.Collaboration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/Sage.Collaboration/Sage.Collaboration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/Sage.Collaboration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/Sage.Collaboration/Sage.Collaboration.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (4/18/2020 @ 10:02:24 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\POS Accounting\POS-Accounting-Setup\PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Sage.Collaboration, Version=2020.2.0.219, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d06c16dde04d83e4
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\POS Accounting\POS-Accounting-Setup\PosAccounting-Sage50-US.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/Sage.Collaboration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/Sage.Collaboration/Sage.Collaboration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/Sage.Collaboration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/POS Accounting/POS-Accounting-Setup/Sage.Collaboration/Sage.Collaboration.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: 0xc00000fd is the error code for stack overflow.

Comment: not got you. Can you brief please?

Comment: Please run Fuslogvw.exe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) and update your question with its output, it will help us to assist you

Comment: @DeJaVo i have added logs from Fuslogvw.exe for your reference

Comment: according to the log, looks like you are missing Sage.Collaboration dll \ exe is your running folder, either your probing config is wrong or you are missing a referenced assembly in the running folder

Comment: i have added the missing dll also in the project but didn't worked. I dont understand that why uts running from /bin/debug folder. it not giving any error for other dll

Comment: you should put all dlls in the same folder were your exe running from . or adjust .config file probing

Comment: yes i have put the dll manually in the folder with that the logs error are gone which is coming with Fuslogvw.exe
but that event viewer error is still exist for stack overlflow.